# How to create a questionnaire type form using Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Ant Design provides a [Dynamic Form Item](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-item), by using that, I can add and remove multiple fields. But now I want do nesting in that, i.e., I want to create a questionnaire like form in which I want to add multiple questions and their respective answers.

Currently, when I am adding questions, its working correct but when I am adding answer to one question, its also adding to the all questions.

The functions of adding and removing questions and answers are as given below:

```
remove = k => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    // can use data-binding to get
    const keys = form.getFieldValue("keys");
    // We need at least one passenger
    if (keys.length === 1) {
      return;
    }

    // can use data-binding to set
    form.setFieldsValue({
      keys: keys.filter(key => key !== k)
    });
  };

  add = () => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    // can use data-binding to get
    const keys = form.getFieldValue("keys");
    const nextKeys = keys.concat(uuid);
    uuid++;
    // can use data-binding to set
    // important! notify form to detect changes
    form.setFieldsValue({
      keys: nextKeys
    });
  };

  remove1 = k1 => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    // can use data-binding to get
    const keys1 = form.getFieldValue("keys1");
    // We need at least one passenger
    if (keys1.length === 1) {
      return;
    }

    // can use data-binding to set
    form.setFieldsValue({
      keys: keys1.filter(key1 => key1 !== k1)
    });
  };

  add1 = () => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    // can use data-binding to get
    const keys1 = form.getFieldValue("keys1");
    const nextKeys1 = keys1.concat(uuid1);
    uuid1++;
    // can use data-binding to set
    // important! notify form to detect changes
    form.setFieldsValue({
      keys1: nextKeys1
    });
  };
```

I have [created a demo on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/z6ww8o28o4).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the functions but in getFieldDecorator:

```
<FormItem>
     {getFieldDecorator(`answer[${k}]`, {
         validate: [
         ...
         ]
         })(<Input type="" placeholder=" Enter Answer" />)
```

You submit the same input value for all inputs.

Without the decorator it works fine and you can put validation to your custom function and call it

```
 <FormItem>
     <Input 
         type="" 
         placeholder=" Enter Answer" 
         // value={this.state.answer}
         // onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} 
      />
 </FormItem>
```

UPD: Added the full code - [Sandbox try](https://codesandbox.io/s/z322qmo7nx)

Comment: Added the sandbox

Comment: It's still not working. When I am adding one answer in one question, its updating to other questions too.

Comment: Hm , probably you're using the same state string variable. Try to use the array and parse it.

Comment: I have fixed the adding issue but now I am struggling with removing. https://codesandbox.io/s/o774v6q845