# How to remove value from array using index (Ant Design specific)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am creating a questionnaire type form using ReactJs and Ant Design. It is a follow up question of [How to create a questionnaire type form using Ant Design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782379/how-to-create-a-questionnaire-type-form-using-ant-design)

Now I am succeeded in adding new questions and their respective answers but not in removing them. Let's suppose I have added three questions and when I am trying to remove any one of them, its always removing the last one. The related code for removing is as follows:

```
remove = k => {
    console.log(k);
    const { form } = this.props;
    // can use data-binding to get
    const keys = form.getFieldValue("keys");
    // We need at least one passenger
    if (keys.length === 1) {
      return;
    }
    keys.splice(k, 1);
    // can use data-binding to set
    form.setFieldsValue({
      keys: keys
    });
    console.log(keys);
  };
```

The complete code can be found as a [demo on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/o774v6q845).

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar in the past. Got rid of the boilerplate of antd's `remove` and replaced with this. Every time I add a row I push that row (object) to `formRows` array then removing like this:

```
  remove = key => {
    const newRows = this.state.formRows.filter(r => r.key !== key)
    this.setState(
      prev => ({
        formRows: newRows
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: Subtle but if you're using the callback method you might as well filter on `prev.formRows` so it's using the latest array at runtime rather than a stale reference otherwise there's no point using the callback method

Comment: Thanks, but what if I use `this.props.form.setFieldsValue` instead of `setState`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get `FormListOperation` and then just

```
 <Form.List name={listName}>
        {(fields, operation) => {
...
operation.remove(index)
```