# How to Create Ant Design group of Dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, dynamic, antd

I'm using [ant design dynamic form](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-item). How I suppose to create a group of dynamic forms

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vvl2yxqr5l

**Scenario**

User need to enter the team name and team members name dynamically.
Is it possible add the dynamic fields inside the dynamic field by ant design.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create a nested dynamic form using ant design dynamic form component. I have also asked the same question [How to create a questionnaire type form using Ant Design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782379/how-to-create-a-questionnaire-type-form-using-ant-design). You need to add your own logic but here I am providing the basic structure:

**To remove team name:**

```
remove = k => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    const keys = form.getFieldValue("newkeys");
    form.setFieldsValue({
      newkeys: keys.filter(key => key !== k)
    });
};
```

**To add team name:**

```
add = () => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    const keys = form.getFieldValue("newkeys");
    const nextKeys = keys.concat(uuid);
    uuid++;
    form.setFieldsValue({
      newkeys: nextKeys
    });
};
```

**To remove team member:**

```
remove1 = (k, l) => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    const keys = form.getFieldValue("answerkey" + k);
    let newkeys = [];
    if (keys) {
      newkeys = keys;
    } else {
      newkeys = [];
    }
    form.setFieldsValue({
      ["answerkey" + k]: newkeys.filter(key => key !== l)
    });
};
```

**To add team member:**

```
add1 = index => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    const keys = form.getFieldValue("answerkey" + index);
    let newkeys = [];
    if (keys) {
      newkeys = keys;
    } else {
      newkeys = [];
    }
    const nextKeys = newkeys.concat(uuid1);
    uuid1++;
    form.setFieldsValue({
      ["answerkey" + index]: nextKeys
    });
};
```

I have created a working demo on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/lxj3364lxl).

Comment: Thanks!! But It shows `Type Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'removeAttribute'` while team name

Comment: @Selvin OK. I am checking in google chrome only. No idea about IE 11.

Comment: If I have two fields in answer. How I can get values? same for questions also demo code here https://codesandbox.io/s/mql8o91opx

Comment: @Selvin You need to work with dynamic keys to get values.

Comment: The code no longer works because it's using antd 3.x. Changing to antd 3.x on Package.js fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

From above answer, I was trying to remove a team name with remove() function but getting some problem and i found this

Use map instead of loop, as map brings values at line 7 after render()

```
newkeys.map((i) => {
    getFieldDecorator("answerkey" + i, { initialValue: [] });
})
```

[Demo video](https://youtu.be/io5YvZaIO2M)